# Webpack build fails without printing error information

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

When I run `npx webpack` on [my project](https://github.com/CarterPape/moab.news), I get the following error:

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/the/path/to/my/project/webpack.config.babel.js' config
[webpack-cli] TypeError: String.prototype.startsWith called on null or undefined
    at startsWith (<anonymous>)
    at node:internal/errors:811:19
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at node:internal/errors:809:16
    at prepareStackTrace (node:internal/errors:96:12)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:38)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/the/path/to/my/project/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
```

As you can see from the error, I have a `webpack.config.babel.js` file and a `.babelrc` file for configuration.

I've attempted to debug the build, but the variable content I get on the exception breakpoint is not very informative.

It looks like I was about to get a useful error message, but then a string came back null, so the error didn't get printed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `.babelrc` to `.babelrc.json`, and the build succeeds.